# Syntax error of Inserting data into mysql in python 3.4 with mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

I am getting data from the web and inserting it into mysql database by the following code. There seems to be a problem in my SQL syntax for adding  records in the data table. The error message goes as follows:

Can someone help with this?

Error message:

```
>  File "D:\Clouds\Dropbox\programming\Python\get youbike info.py", line
> 33, in <module>
>     cursor.execute(insert_data)   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 559,
> in execute
>     self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line
> 494, in cmd_query
>     result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))   File
> "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line
> 396, in _handle_result
>     raise errors.get_exception(packet) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%s, %s, %s,
> %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)' at line 1
```

My Code

```
import urllib.request
import gzip
import json
import mysql.connector
url = "http://data.taipei/youbike"
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,"data.gz")
f=gzip.open('data.gz','r')
jdata = f.read()
f.close()
data = json.loads(jdata.decode('utf-8'))
stationNo =1
cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user='root', host='127.0.0.1', database='bike')
cursor = cnx.cursor()
for key,value in data["retVal"].items():
    sno = value["sno"]
    sna = value["sna"]
    sarea = value["sarea"]
    lat = value["lat"]
    lng = value["lng"]
    ar = value["ar"]
    sareaen = value["sareaen"]
    snaen = value["snaen"]
    aren = value["aren"]
    print("NO." + sno + " " + sna)
    stationNo+=1
    insert_data = ("INSERT INTO info "
                   "(sno, sna, sarea, lat, lng, ar, sareaen, snaen, aren) "
                   "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

    cursor.execute(insert_data)
    cnx.commit()
cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cursor.execute(insert_data, sno, sna, sarea, ...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not passing any data to the values section, the placeholder %s are going blank as there you are not passing data

```
insert_data = ("INSERT INTO info "
                   "(sno, sna, sarea, lat, lng, ar, sareaen, snaen, aren) "
                   "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")

    cursor.execute(insert_data,(sno, sna, sarea, lat, lng, ar, sareaen, snaen, aren))
```

try this

Answer (score -1):

To help fault-find, do a

```
print "("INSERT INTO info "
       "sno, sna, sarea, lat, lng, ar, sareaen, snaen, aren) "
       "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)")
```

and check the values for any double-quote marks; the presence of any will definitely cause the SQL to break.

Also, by "getting data from the web" and inserting it straight into your code as you've done opens up your app to some very serious SQL-insertion attacks, so perhaps it is best to spend some time sanitizing the web input, in addition to stripping quotation marks.